# Laravel 10 Livewire 3 - "validation" attribute doesn't work

Tags: laravel-livewire

I want to use the "#[Validate]" attribute to validate a form post. When I run it I receive the error:

```
  Missing [$rules/rules()] property/method on Livewire component: [contactform].
```

...seems to be ignoring the validation attribute entirely:

```
namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\Attributes\Validate;

class Kontaktform extends Component
{

    #[Validate('required',message: 'Please provide your name')]
    #[Validate('max:255')]
    public $name = '';

.
.
.
   
   //Validate and submit
    public function submitForm(){
    $validated = $this->validate();  <-----error points to this line :S
    dd($validated);

   }
.
.
.
```